# Django connection cursor scope

Tags: django

```py
        with connections['other_db'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("""SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                                SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
                                SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
                                SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
                                SET ANSI_PADDING ON""")
            cursor.execute(sql, [self.sonumber, void_reason, rep.number])
            result = cursor.fetchone()
```

As above, do the `SET` commands inside that cursor will make changes to the connection globally if connection is persisted (side effects)?

Comment: Which DB backend are you using? You can configure `OPTIONS` in your database config to run these sorts of commands on connection to your database https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-OPTIONS. Example for MySQL in the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#creating-your-tables

Comment: I am running MSSQL, this is existing code I picked up on, I don't necessarily want those config to stick around, just curious the scope of those changes.

Comment: You just want to know if those `SET` commands affect all connections to the DB?

Comment: Yes correct, potentially affecting the next request cycle if connection is reused

Comment: You have to add the `GLOBAL` keyword to change the value on the database and not just the current session/connection. MySQL can have some strange behaviour though so who knows, if I had the option I would use any database other than MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

Comment: @IainShelvington it's MSSQL not MySQL :)

Comment: Ah sorry, which database engine package are you using? MSSQL is not supported out-of-the-box in Django

Comment: this https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/